# Create a wargame with mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I'd like to know the way to add a "token" (draggable & deletable image) to a mapbox project. My goal is to create a wargame that can be played over the maps, at different zooming levels, and so each token (military unit)should have fix dimensions, in order to became smaller when zooming out. I know how to create a draggable marker, since it is in the [mapbox.js examples library](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/draggable-marker/), but I have no idea how to make draggable an fix dimensions image (such a polygon or an overlaying image added to the map)

I know very little about code but I can copy/paste or customize styles.

Comment: I think you'll need to learn a little coding to get the results you're after. However, check out [Leaflet's `Icon` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) for some of the object properties you'll need. Also, you might be able to glean some tips from [this example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html). Since Mapbox uses Leaflet under the hood, I recommend using "Leaflet" and not "Mapbox" for one of your search terms when you're googling for examples and such--if you're only searching for Mapbox examples, you might be missing the best stuff.

Comment: By the way, here's [a JSFiddle I review from time to time](http://jsfiddle.net/hx2yxdc0/) that shows how to add a simple, draggable marker icon that changes the mouse pointer to a crosshairs symbol. You might find it somewhat useful.